# Is it correct to say "I agree with his points made."

Tags: grammaticality

Some others told me it was correct, but I thought it is supposed to be "I agree with the points he made."

If yes, then how is it correct? I'm trying to see how it works, but I cannot see how this statement makes sense or is equivalent to the wording I'm used to.

Comment: You should ask "some others" to justify their view. "I agree with the points he made" is correct and so would be "I agree with his points" or even "I agree with the points made."

Answer (score -1):

I think both is correct, but with different aspects in focus. Using "I agree with the points he made" he focus is on that HE made his points. The latter although focuses on the points was made.

Comment: Can you explain why you think both are correct? I am not aware of any dialects in which the sentence in the title would be correct.